# How can I close an empty pane in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, pane

I often end up with lots of empty panes in Eclipse that can only be minimized but not destroyed. How do I close these?

#### Update:

In this screenshot you can see two minimized on the upper left and several on the right hand side. In the center are four more. They only seem to be restorable in the Debug mode.

http://img406.imageshack.us/img406/9900/eclipse1.png

Comment: I can't see the screenshot. This is how I interpret the question: http://i.imgur.com/R9f0lb0.png , and jen's answer solved it for me (dragging the Main.java tab there). Still, I'm unable to have a single "pane".

Answer (score 15):

this happened to me, too.  What worked for me (based on FilmJ and douncon's comments) was to open a class file, then drag that tab over the top of the empty pane.

Comment: This worked for me, too. Much better than resetting and rebuilding the perspective.

Comment: Same here. Eclipse is such garbage.

Answer (score 10):

Select Window -> Reset Perspective. That should reset the current perspective (what you call "mode") to its' initial state, (hopefully) closing all irrelevant views.

Something seems terribly wrong with your Eclipse. Maybe you should reinstall it. It is possible that you installed a buggy plugin.

Comment: I tried resetting the perspective in Java EE / Debug / SVN perspectives but those "empty editors" persist. However I cannot "restore" them now.

Comment: Try starting with a new workspace. You can import all your projects to the new workspace. Under File -> Switch Workspace -> Other... simply point to an empty (or non-existing) folder and start fresh.

Comment: This solution did work for me. Just going to the perspective causing the problem and resetting... thx.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, what do you mean by pane? Eclipse has:

- Windows (Eclipse itself, e.g. instance)
- Documents (tabs)
- Views (properties, tasks, explorer, etc)

If by 'pane' you mean document editors, you have problems either with your Eclipse version or most likely one of the installed plugins.

Each View also can be closed (except maybe some project types (perspectives) of which I'm not aware). For CDT (C/C++) you can close practically everything.

I'll recommend you [download](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) latest Eclipse version with no plugins, extract it to different folder, and check if that happens again. If yes, please explain more in details (like Eclipse version, perspective you are using, any side plugins, etc).

Also a good places are Eclipse [community forum](http://eclipse.org/forums/), [mailing list](http://eclipse.org/mail/) and [bugz](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/) :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. For me it helped to go into the right perspective and activate the functionality that caused the window in the first place. Once I reactivated the functionality, in my case "QNX Memory Analysis perspective", I was able to close all the windows one by one.

The conclusion is you have to refill the empty windows with content and then you will be able to close them properly.

Answer (score 0):

So, it's really very easy for this to happen, if you open an editor that's incompatible with the existing editor, you can often end up having to place it outside of the tab list in one of your editor panes, then you might clear or copy that, typically while trying to add that view to a tab list.

In any case, what it's done is create a new editor, and all you need to do is drag some file to that empty editor window giving it some form of context, then close it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I followed @zvikico, but instead of just resetting, I first reset and then closed all the perspectives. Please follow the following to fix the problem. It worked for me:

```
Window -> Perspective -> Reset perspective..
```

After resetting follow below:

```
Window -> Perspective -> Close All Perspectives
```